# How to use IObjectWithChangeTracker Interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I have been searching EVERYWHERE for this IObjectWithChangeTracker Interface that I think I need for a problem in my current project and I FINALLY discover (via [this](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2010/08/24/using-self-tracking-entities-with-silverlight-4-and-entity-framework-4.aspx)) that it isn't actually built into .Net

What I still can't figure out is how in the world do I use it!!  I can't find the code anywhere, I have no idea what these T4 things are.  Or where I find them.  Someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That site is specific for silverlight - entity framework already has self tracking entities.You can attach new objects you create as modified, deleted, etc, but altering a current object automatically tracks its state. So - what are you trying to do? : )

t4 files are code generation files. You can basically include a template (.tt file) in your project and when you run your project, the file is processed and generally create one or more code output files. 
See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx